# Angular Mustache evaluation - why does this code behave this way?

Tags: angularjs

In the following code:

```
<!doctype html>    
<html lang="en" ng-app>      
    <head>        
        <meta charset="utf-8">        
        <title>My HTML File</title>        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />        
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>      
    </head>    
    <body>
        <div id="div1" style="display:none;">This disappears</div>
        <p>Nothing here {{2 + "3" + document.getElementById("div1").innerText + "." }}</p>      
    </body>
</html>
```

I expected to see an error or failing that I'd expect "23This disappears." What I do see is "23." (Notice the missing "This disappears")

It's obvious that the mustache is not doing a direct evaluation, but what is actually going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The 2 is being converted into a string and then concatenated with the "3" string, because you can't concatenate an integer with a string.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I should have been more clear. The question is referring to the document.getElement...innerText. Angular is doing an evaluation but definitely not eval. What is puzzling is that it gets the "." but fails the DOM object. Which leads be to believe that the entire page is being cloned or there is some other mechanism to fail gracefully. 2+"3" = 23 is not surprising.

Comment: The CSS tree will get rebuilt first:
`<div id="div1" style="display:none;">This disappears</div>`
Then the **$compiler** will work with the DOM that has an empty div.

Comment: Is this accurate? What I understand at this point (from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) is that the `{{ code }}` is not JavaScript but a new interpreted language.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS expressions are JavaScript-like code snippets that are evaluated by AngularJS in the context of the current model scope, rather than within the scope of the global context (window).

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression